# SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY does not work

Tags: spl

I'm facing a huge difficulty right now. I did not succeed in finding how to fix it.
I'm trying to display csv datas without empty lines. I thought the SPL library could permit it. But whatever i do i can't find why it's not working. 
Could you?
Here's my code (quite simple):

```html
<?php  
 // Lecture du fichier csv
 $csv = new SplFileObject('fichiers/tempo/test.csv', 'r');
 // Flags pour ignorer les lignes vides
 $csv->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV | SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY | SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE); 
 $csv->setCsvControl(';');
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
  
        <title>Nas - Insertion de données</title>
  
 </head>
 
 <body>

  

  <table>
   
   <?php
    $tableau = array();
    // On parcours les lignes du fichier csv en lecture ==> $csv
    foreach($csv as $line){
     echo '<tr>';
     foreach($line as $var){
      echo '<td>-'.$var.'</td>';      
     }
        echo '</tr>';      
    }
   ?>
    
  </table>
 
 </body>
  
</html>
```

My flags do nothing, and i don't know what i'm doing wrong.....
Thank you.

Comment: This should work as expected. Can you maybe post the CSV file and at least the PHP version you are working on?

Answer (score 2):

You should use these flags to ignore empty lines:

```php
$file->setFlags(
    SplFileObject::READ_CSV |
    SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY |
    SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD  |
    SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time. I tried with php 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0 but it did nothing. Then i choose to put the following test to every loop:

```html
foreach($csv as $line){
 // Ignoring empty lines
 if(implode($line) == null)continue;
    ...
```

At least it works!

My Csv is something like:
Wine List;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;
;This wine is stored at the chƒteau or at our supplier's warehouse and will be available for collection later on.;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;
Product Type;Vintage;Wine;Appellation;Classement;Qty;Size;Price;W-A;W-S;Comments
Red wine;2013;Aiguilhe (d');Castillon - c“tes de bordeaux;;216;750 mL;11,80 ?;87-89s;86-89;
Red wine;2012;Aiguilhe (d');Castillon - c“tes de bordeaux;;168;750 mL;12,50 ?;89-91;89;
Red wine;2011;Aiguilhe (d');Castillon - c“tes de bordeaux;;395;750 mL;12,60 ?;88;89;